# How do I load a file in AWS S3 into Tensorflow model using tf.data.TextLineDataset()

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3

I am able to read in the csv file stored in s3 using the following. But how can I load the same csv file into a Tensorflow model using  tf.data.TextLineDataset()?

```
AWS_KEY = 'aaa'
AWS_SECRET = '123'
aws_connection = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('my-awesome-bucket')
fileName = "train.csv"
content = bucket.get_key(fileName).get_contents_as_string()
```

Thank you!